# Have two field with the same type in one page with arbitrary place.

Tags: orchardcms

I created the CategoryPart and I added two text field to it. I want to add some custom data in the page between two text fields data. The problem is when I want to specify the place of the text field in Placement.info I just have one Shap "Fields_Common_Text" for all the text fields in the page so I can't specify different places for different fields with the same type. Is there any way to do it in Orchard? Thanks in advance.

my Placement.info is like this:

```
   <Placement>
      <Match DisplayType ="Detail">
         <Place Parts_Category="Content:9"></Place>
        <Place Fields_Common_Text="Content:10"></Place> 
      </Match>
   </Placement>
```

The display method in driver:

```
   protected override DriverResult Display(CategoryPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {          
        return ContentShape("Parts_Category", () => shapeHelper.Parts_Category(CategoryPart: part));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. You can specify placement for the items with the shape type and the name of the field. For example, if your text fields are named `CategoryName` and `CategoryType`, you can define following placement:

```
<Placement>
  <Match DisplayType ="Detail">
     <Place Fields_Common_Text-CategoryName="Content:9"></Place>
     <Place Fields_Common_Text-CategoryType="Content:10"></Place> 
  </Match>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it woks. the interesting that happened is I tried this way with different Alternate template so instead of "Fields.Common.Text-Benefits" I created "Fields.Common.Text-Category-Benefits" and it didn't work. so we have to use specific template to be able to do it?

Comment: Yes, you have to specify the name of the field. You can cater it to the type with something like this `<Match ContentType="Category"><Place Fields.Common.Text-Benefits="Content:1"/></Match>`