# Orchard CMS: How to add a Taxonomy field to a Content Type on a migration?

Tags: orchardcms, taxonomy

I need to define a new Content Type having a Taxonomy field on my module's migrations.
I guess I need to do something like this:

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("ContentTypeName",
            cfg => cfg
                .WithPart("TermsPart", builder => builder
                    .WithSetting(...
```

But I could not make it work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally made it thanks to [Giscard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568888/adding-a-field-to-a-contenttype-in-a-orchard-datamigration).
The important thing to know about Orchard is that a **field can't be attached to a content type**. When you attach it to a content type in the admin UI, Orchard does some magic behind the scenes to hide this fact, it creates a content part inside that content type, with the same name as the content type, and then attaches the field(s) to that new content part.

So here is the solution:

```
        //Create new table for the new part
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable(typeof(SampleRecord).Name, table => table
            .ContentPartRecord()
            .Column("SampleColumn", DbType.String)
        );

        //Attach field to the new part
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(
            typeof(SamplePart).Name, 
            cfg => cfg
                .Attachable()
                .WithField("Topic", fcfg => fcfg
                    .OfType("TaxonomyField")
                    .WithDisplayName("Topic")
                    .WithSetting("Taxonomy", "Topics")
                    .WithSetting("LeavesOnly", "true")
                    .WithSetting("SingleChoice", "true")
                    .WithSetting("Required", "true"))
            );

        //Attach part to the new Content Type
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Sample",
                 cfg => cfg
                     .WithPart(typeof(SamplePart).Name
                ));
```

I created a table with a column named "SampleColumn" and I attached a field "Topic" for the Taxonomy named "Topics".
Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: It seems like this approach needs a slight rework for the current Orchard version (i'm using 1.9) to get the defined settings applied correctly. E.g. using `.WithSetting("Taxonomy", "Topics")` does not work while using `.WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.Taxonomy", "Topics")` does work.